# what is the similarity function and how is the query transformed with spread activation techniques

Tags: information-retrieval

We have an information retrieval project in which we should build a search engine for a website we made the first semester.

Anyway I'm evaluating existing models when I stumbled upon spread activation.

I understand that there is a graph in which nodes are documents and links are the edges between them, I also understand the graph is weighted.

Some papers said nodes can be terms,citation,etc. What I didn't find is the similarity function and the query.

Where is the query in this graph ? and how is the similarity computed ?

I understand there are many models that use spread activation, I think one or two example models would be enough, I want to understand how is spread activation applied on the query in particular.